# Add items to tab's context menu in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In Google Chrome web browser I would like to add options such as "Bookmark Selected Tab", "Close tab to the left" to the tab's context menu.

Is it possible? If possible, what is the API I must check?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible.

The closest API that exists is [`contextMenus` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus).

However, if you look at the [available "contexts"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#type-ContextType) (objects whose menu you can change), there is no "tab" there.

So, at least currently, you can't modify a tab's context menu.