# Customize Tab Context Menu in Firefox

Tags: firefox, sdk, contextmenu

I am trying to find a way to customize - add more items, to be specific - to the *tab* context menu in Firefox through their add-ons SDK. So far I know that we can customize the [page context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu) only. Does anyone know how we could accomplish what I'm trying to do?

There's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950552/add-items-to-tabs-context-menu-in-google-chrome) asked about Google Chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

If its any help still, here's what I've accomplished so far in order to add a 'menuitem' to the tab right-click menu for youtube.com

```
// Import necessary APIs
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var { MatchPattern } = require("sdk/util/match-pattern");
var pattern = new MatchPattern("*.youtube.com");

// Localization
var _ = require("sdk/l10n").get;
// Convert higher-level object to lower-level one
var { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");

tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
  if (pattern.test(tab.url)) {
    let doc = viewFor(tab.window).document
    let menu = doc.getElementById("tabContextMenu");
    let newtab = doc.createElementNS("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul","menuitem");
    newtab.setAttribute("id", "contexttab-newtab");
    newtab.setAttribute("label", _("newtab_string"));
    newtab.setAttribute("accesskey", _("newtabaccesskey_string"));
    newtab.setAttribute("oncommand", "BrowserOpenTab();");
    menu.insertBefore(newtab, menu.firstChild);
  }
});
```

The code from `let menu = doc.getElementById("tabContextMenu");` is shamelessly plagiarized from the 'New Tab in Tab Context Menu' at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-in-tab-context-menu/

The basic idea is that you need to convert your tab.window object into a 'chrome window' (the lower level–and older–XUL-type object/api) according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/windows#Converting_to_chrome_windows) page. Then you create the context `menuitem` as a XUL object directly.

Hope this helps.